# How can I implement a good 'time on page' algorithm for web analytics?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I'm aware that the usual analytics won't show the time spent on the last page, and that page timing is a bit of a crapshoot:

- Someone opens multiple tabs on a single web site.
- Someone opens a tab in background and doesn't go to it.
- Someone opens a bunch of tabs in background, and reads them one by one.
- Someone visits my page, and leaves (bounce)

I'm hoping that some form of event tracking may give me an alternate metric to use.

Consider the following scenario:

User finds one of my pages on google.
User goes to my page.
User leaves.

This *could* mean that the user came, saw that 'nursery' in my case meant 'tree nursery' and that I wasn't a suitable place for their pre-schooler. Time on page 3 seconds.

Or it *could* mean that the user came with a question about a specific tree, read my info, found the answer he needed and left. Time on page 4 minutes.

How do I tell them apart?

Scenario two:

User searches for maple trees.

Right click my site, open in new tab.
Repeat 6 times for other sites.
Reads them in reverse order.
My site has been up now for 14 minutes, but he looks at it, thinks, "I've seen all this before" exit.

So the signal has a lot of noise in it.  Can be useful for comparing to last year, but not really a good measure of engagement.

---

Increasingly I'm seeing sites that track that upward swoop of the mouse, and bring forth a Billy May popup, "Wait, there's more!"

- Where do I start learning about events?
- Is there an event to detect if the page currently has a mouse cursor in it?
- Is there an event to in effect run a timer for N seconds since the last mouse movement, pausing the timer, restarting the timer if the mouse moves again, pausing if the mouse moves to a different tab, restarting if it comes back into the tab and report that time on page exit?

So the ideal page timer does something like this:

- Detect when mouse moves in viewport. Sends 'viewer engaged event'
- Timer starts when mouse moves into view port, or tab becomes active.
- Inactivity timer starts when mouse stops moving.  After N seconds sends a 'viewer no longer engaged' event. Timer stops.
- Mouse moves, keyboard active in that viewport, viewport scrolled: timer resumes. 'Viewer engaged'
- Mouse exits window.  Sends 'viewer no longer engaged' Timer stoped.
- tab is closed, Sends 'window closed event' and viewer engaged time.

Is this possible?  Am I asking the right questions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes all of the above is possible, however depending on you need to consider some legal boundries. Apart from that you can consult the documentation

JQuery: [jQuery Events API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/)

Javascript:[Javascript Event Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Events)

If you need a resource that is a little bit more hands-on you could check-out:

[Mozilla Introduction to Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)

However, just collecting the Data is easiest part of this project, storing, processing and visualizing it in a meaningful way will be much harder than just collecting data.